# Is there a way in python to read a text block within a csv cell and only select cell data based on key word with in text block?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis, data-extraction

I am working with a CSV file in **Pandas/Python** and I need to find when a supplier response was submitted.
The column "time Line" contains the info I'm looking for and can vary on how much information was put into the response at the time but the keyword I am looking for is the same.

Text block

**(This is the sub-section I need!)**

```
October 29, 2021 10:34:30 AM -05:00 - Jim
Supplier assignment notification sent to supplier "ALB-example" - Alex (alex.example@examplecorp.com)
--------
```

```
November 04, 2021 07:06:31 PM -05:00 - Levi 
A-Quality Dept assigned as approver
--------
November 01, 2021 05:11:19 PM -05:00 - Jim 
CAR #454 created from this record
--------
October 29, 2021 10:34:30 AM -05:00 - Jim 
Supplier assignment notification sent to supplier "ALB-Aeroexample" - Alex (alex.example@example.com)
--------
October 29, 2021 10:34:28 AM -05:00 - Jim 
NCP Updated with the following changes:
 + Supplier assigned changed from "False to True
```

This text block is in one cell and I haven't figured out how to go about it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe has a "time line" column:

`new_df = df.loc[df['time Line'].str.contains('the string you are looking for')]`

this will create a new dataframe with all rows that contains the string you need, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thank you, this helped find the text within the cell. Now trying to extract the date time stamp of that specific section in the cell, is that possible?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly how to do it without the data, but I guess that if the first line is always the date you can split txt.split("\n"), select the item 0 of the split and then replace the text part with regex and cast to date... Not going to be easy, though